# basic ng-grid example not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm new to angularjs and ng-grid...I'm currently going through a simple exampe for ng-grid, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.css" data-semver="2.0.11" data-require="ng-grid@*" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" data-semver="2.1.1" data-require="jquery@*"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.7" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.min.js" data-semver="2.0.11" data-require="ng-grid@*"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my js:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
  {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
  {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
  {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
  $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
  $scope.title = "ng-grid example";
});
```

I also created an example of my issue in Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9fEF8sBAMhaMxWimLfTn?p=preview

Thanks!

Shanna

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation where you got this from found [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/) incorrectly states the following

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid']);
```

Their plunkr link on that same page has the correct syntax of

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
```

found [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/).

Answer (score 2):

You are importing ng-grid. So in your module dependencies it should be like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
```

Check this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BCOWqo9MUPNYHQkjN1qh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work for sure.**

This is my html

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
            <script src="myscript.hs"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions1"  id="grid1"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Comment: I'm an angular newbie, but it seems that one thing wrong with this example is that it points to a local copy of angular.js.  OK, so I added that. How can I tell that it loaded correctly? It also looks like the style.ccs is local, but where does it come from? At any rate, your example does not work. Maybe with global file references...

Answer (score -1):

This is my js.

```
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData1 = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50, address:"bangalore", pin_code:44555},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, address:"mysore", pin_code:74034},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27, address:"bellary", pin_code:88394},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29, address:"ramanagara", pin_code:73883},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34, address:"cpt", pin_code:34456}];
    $scope.gridOptions1 = { data: 'myData1',
              rowHeight: 25,
              multiSelect:false,
              enableRowSelection: true,
              columnDefs: [
               {
                 field: "name",
                 displayName: "Name",
                 width: '25%',
                 height: '50px',                
               },
               {
                 field: "age",
                 displayName: "Age",
                 width: '25%',
                 height: '50px',

               },
               {
                 field: "address",
                 displayName: "Address",
                 width: '25%',
                 height: '50px'
               },
               {
                 field: "pin_code",
                 displayName: "PIN",
                 width: '25%',
                 height: '50px',
               }

               ]};
});
</script>
```