# How to get ng-grid for Angular working?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have looked at the following link: http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/
and I've tried following the instructions but I still cannot get ng-grid to work.

In step #2, it says to reference ngGrid's javascript and css files, but I don't know which of the dozens of js files to reference, and there weren't any css files included in the download link at the top of the page.

I've tried replacing 'ui.grid' with 'ngGrid', as this answer recommended: [basic ng-grid example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991155/basic-ng-grid-example-not-working).

I've tried following their documentation as well, but that also didn't work.

I've tried referencing this css file:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
```

Here's my js reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
```

Here's a snippet of my module:

```
angular.module('app', [
        'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angular-spinkit', 'app.controller', 'app.factory', 'ngGrid',
```

Here's my html:

```
<div class="grid-style" ng-grid="vm.gridOptions">
    </div>
```

And here's my controller:

```
vm.myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
             { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
             { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
             { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
             { name: "Enos", age: 34 }];
        vm.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
```

I'm using ui router as well, not sure if that has something to do with the issue.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe try using ui-grid instead as it is the latest and ng-grid is becoming unsupported.  here is a link to a simple and quick page to get things working.  http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro

Comment: Do you get any javascript exception?

Comment: Yes, Yori, I do get javascript execution.  I set another variable in my controller and it displays the value on the page correctly.

Comment: Scott, I followed the link you provided but the first instruction is to reference release/ui-grid-unstable.css and /release/ui-grid-unstable.js, but  I don't see where those files are located.

Comment: I mean Javascript Exception... if yes, what is the Exception Message?

Comment: You can find ui-grid-unstable.css and .js on ui-grid github repository:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release

The unstable versions are development versions, you will also find the stable version on the subdirectores (e.g.: 3.0.0-rc.19). Cheers